# How to bind horizontal values of a table to a vertical values of another table in oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

i have 2 tables .

[image]

The columns start with attributes are change based on department. the description of attributes are here

[image]

My requirement is to get the values of each attributes with its primary key based on the department as table bellow.

[image]

Honestly i am stuck on this problem in my program. I have no permission to change the tables and there is no common unique key column.i would appreciate if anyone could provide me a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with a as (
    select a.*, row_number() over (partition by department order by attributeID) rn
      from attributes a),
  e as (
    select employeeId, department, attribute1, 1 rn from employees union all
    select employeeId, department, attribute2, 2 rn from employees union all
    select employeeId, department, attribute3, 3 rn from employees
  )
select e.employeeId, a.attributeid, e.department, a.attribute, a.meaning, 
       e.attribute1 as value 
  from e join a on a.department=e.department and a.rn=e.rn 
  order by e.employeeId, a.attributeid
```

Test data and output:

```
create table employees (employeeID number(3), name varchar2(10), department varchar2(5), age number(3), attribute1 varchar2(10), attribute2 varchar2(10), attribute3 varchar2(10));
insert into employees values (1, 'john', 'IT', 22, 'attr1val1', 'attr2val2',  null);
insert into employees values (2, 'jane', 'HR', 32, 'attr1val3', 'attr2val4',  'attr3val5');
insert into employees values (3, 'joe',  'HR', 23, 'attr1val6', 'attr2val7',  'attr3val8');
insert into employees values (4, 'jack', 'IT', 45, 'attr1val9', 'attr2val10', null);

create table attributes (attributeID number(3), department varchar2(10), attribute varchar2(10), meaning varchar2(10));
insert into attributes values (1, 'IT', 'attribute1', 'laptoptype');
insert into attributes values (2, 'IT', 'attribute2', 'networkloc');
insert into attributes values (3, 'HR', 'attribute1', 'location');
insert into attributes values (4, 'HR', 'attribute2', 'position');
insert into attributes values (5, 'HR', 'attribute3', 'allocation');

EMPLOYEEID ATTRIBUTEID DEPARTMENT ATTRIBUTE  MEANING    VALUE
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1           1 IT         attribute1 laptoptype attr1val1
         1           2 IT         attribute2 networkloc attr2val2
         2           3 HR         attribute1 location   attr1val3
         2           4 HR         attribute2 position   attr2val4
         2           5 HR         attribute3 allocation attr3val5
         3           3 HR         attribute1 location   attr1val6
         3           4 HR         attribute2 position   attr2val7
         3           5 HR         attribute3 allocation attr3val8
         4           1 IT         attribute1 laptoptype attr1val9
         4           2 IT         attribute2 networkloc attr2val10
```

---

**Edit**: Explanation

In answer I used [`with`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) 
clause just to divide solution into readable steps. You can move them into `from` clause of main query if it is 
more comfortable for you. Anyway: subquery `a` reads data from table `attributes` and adds number for rows, 
so for each department they are allways numbered from 1. I used [row_number()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) for that. Subquery `e` unions (all) required attributes and numbers 
them accordingly. Numbers generated in both subqueries are then used in main join: `a.department=e.department and a.rn=e.rn`.

---

**Alternative 1** - if you are using Oracle 11g you could use the [unpivot](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/UNPIVOT). See what is generated by subquery, and how it is joined with `attributes` table:

```
with e as (
    select employeeId, name, department, attribute, value from employees
      unpivot (value for attribute in ("ATTRIBUTE1", "ATTRIBUTE2", "ATTRIBUTE3"))  
  )
select e.employeeId, a.attributeid, e.department, a.attribute, 
       a.meaning, e.value 
  from e join attributes a on a.department=e.department 
                          and lower(a.attribute)=lower(e.attribute)
  order by e.employeeId, a.attributeid;
```

---

**Alternative 2** - with hierarchical subquery generator (subquery `r`), realised by [`connect by`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) which simple creates numbers from 1, 2, 3 which are next joined with `employees` and proper attribute 
is attached as value in `case` clause. Rest is made in similiar way like in original answer.

```
with a as (
    select a.*, row_number() over (partition by department order by attributeID) rn
      from attributes a),
  r as (select level rn from dual connect by level<=3),
  e as (
    select employeeId, department, rn,
           case when r.rn = 1 then attribute1
                when r.rn = 2 then attribute2
                when r.rn = 3 then attribute3
           end value
      from employees cross join r
  )
select e.employeeId, a.attributeid, e.department, a.attribute,
       a.meaning, e.value
  from e join a on a.department=e.department and a.rn=e.rn
  order by e.employeeId, a.attributeid
```

All three versions gave me the same output. I also tested first option on similiar table with 100k rows and get output in few seconds (for 5 attributes). Please test all solutions and try to understand them. If you can use unpivot version I would prefer this.
Sorry for delayed explanation and any language mistakes.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the answer and all the extra test data and result and everything . it is a great help .actually in my real dataset there are 20 attributes so which means more unions and it will get slow with this query right

Comment: Maybe you could use some complicated `case` here, but it would be much better to reorganise tables - add new table like "Emp_Atr" (emp_id, attr_id, value) - this way data would be normalised. 
But you wrote that you cannot change structure and add tables. Check efficiency of `union all` version. Maybe other users will have better ideas.

Comment: Hi can you explain this query for me  ?

Comment: @PonderStibbons...did you know the OP [opened an entirely new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923476/can-anyone-explain-this-query) simply because you did not explain your answer here.

Comment: @Parfait - thanks for the info. I planned to explain current solution and present some new idea later because now I don't have access to Oracle and don't want to show something unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

The [WITH clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) was added with Oracle 9.2 and should do the trick.  For the other attributes just add more sub queries where the filter is att.attribute = 'attribute2' or 'Attribute3'...

```
WITH e AS
(SELECT emp.employee_ID, emp.department, emp.attribute1
FROM employee emp),
a AS (SELECT att.attribute_id, att.attribute, att.meaning
FROM attribute_TYPE att
WHERE att.attribute = 'attribute1')a
SELECT e.employeeid, att.attributeid, e.department, a.attribute, 
a.meaning e.attribute1
FROM e  JOIN a ON e.department = a.department
```

Comment: Actually I have 20 attributes . so for each I have to write a sub query?

Comment: I take it you inherited  this schema...or mess as some might call it? Twenty attributes, twenty sub queries will work but there are better but more complex ways.  Will think about it.

Comment: Thank you it would be a big help